# document.getElementById() can't find any matches on page

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, dom

**i have this html code:**

```
import { currentSlide } from './Carusel';


<div className='app__mainpage'>
                <div className='app__mainpage_banners'>
                    <img id='app__banners-banner' src={images.banner_first} alt='Банер' />
                    <img id='app__banners-banner' src={images.banner_two} alt='Банер' />
                    <img id='app__banners-banner' src={images.banner_three} alt='Банер' />
                </div>
                <div className='app__mainpage_cigarettes'>
                    <svg className='app__cigarettes-arrow active' fill='#6C6C6C' onClick={currentSlide(1)} ... BLA-BLA-BLA boring svg code </svg>
                </div>
 </div>
```

**and that js code:**

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

export function currentSlide(n){
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

export function showSlides(n){
  var i;
  var images = document.getElementById("app__banners-banner");
  var cigarettes = document.getElementsByClassName("app__cigarettes-arrow");

  if(n > images.length){
    slideIndex = 1;
  }

  if(n < 1){
    slideIndex = slideIndex.length;
  }

  for(i = 0; i < images.length; i++){
    images[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  for(i = 0; i < cigarettes.length; i++){
    cigarettes[i].className = cigarettes[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }

  images[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  cigarettes[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
```

in `js` file i have finction called `showSlides`, when i click `svg` object onClick parameter should call `showSlides` function and so go on

The problem is `Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "length", images is null`. I am fully understand that `js` can't find some object with id: `app__banners-banner` and so can't fill `var` named `images`. But why? Cause that object obiously exist

I expected that `var` variable will be filled by object called `app__banners-banner` and my code gonna work

Comment: This is not the react way to code things.

Comment: okay, how can i fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general a singular function returns a single object.  In this case, getElementByID returns a single element if found, and null if not.  Objects don't automatically have a "length" attribute.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

Comment: Which img does it return when they all have the same id?

Comment: you see, i watched some youtube video and this guy did it, sooooo if it works for him should work for me

Comment: this smells of trolling, but the ID attribute in HTML is required to be unique.   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id   
      Classes and other similar attributes like "name" don't have this uniqueness.  Since the function you're using is "getElement" singular, it expects a single element with the given ID and will return that element or null.  If there are multiple elements with the ID, the behavior is not guaranteed since the documents breaks the unique ID specification.

Comment: It smells like the [Socratic method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socratic_method) and your answer is now complete. +1

Comment: I was referring to 3dmax's comment - the "some guy on youtube" seemed either sarcastic or straight trolling ‍♂️

Answer (score 2):

There's a general rule that all id's on the DOM should be unique. It you wanted to group elements together, then adding them to the same class would make more sense. You might want to do something like this

```
  <img id='app__banners-banner-1' src={images.banner_first} alt='Банер' />
  <img id='app__banners-banner-2' src={images.banner_two} alt='Банер' />
  <img id='app__banners-banner-3' src={images.banner_three} alt='Банер' />
```

If you are using react you may want to do some research on `useState` and other hooks that could satisfy your needs. Holding your data in state and updating state on click is a more react way of doing things.